# Upload and then resize images

Tags: upload, fuelphp

I am having trouble with simple picture upload. I already tried that the uploading part separately works perfectly only after adding the Image resize functionality gives unknown error.

```
public function post_add_image()
  {
    \Upload::process(array(
        'path'        => '../images/',
        'normalize'   => true,
        'change_case' => 'lower',
        'randomize'   => true,
        'ext_whitelist' => array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'),
        'max_size'    => 1024 * 1024,

    ));

    if (!\Upload::is_valid()) {
      return $this->response(\Upload::get_errors());
    } else {
      foreach (\Upload::get_files() as $file) {

        // Here comes ERROR
        $image = Image::load($file['file'], false, $file['extension']);
        $image->crop_resize(800, 600);
        $image->save('test');

      }
    }

    //\Upload::save();

    return $this->response(\Upload::get_files());
  }
```

And the error:

RuntimeException [ Error ]: The library does not support this filetype for /tmp/phpOnZReS.

COREPATH/classes/image/driver.php @ line

And I made var_dump of the uploaded file:

```
array(10) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(27) "crunchbang-logo-minimal.png"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["size"]=>
  int(278)
  ["field"]=>
  string(10) "pictures:0"
  ["file"]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpDdTLwJ"
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(23) "crunchbang-logo-minimal"
  ["mimetype"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
}
```

Comment: What version of FuelPHP are you using? Forcing the image extension only became available in version 1.3.

Comment: Well I am using version 1.5 linux and yes the gd extension is loaded. At least the image resize works after the image is already uploaded to server but this move takes extra resources.

Comment: Have to check if the upload path is correct? Can you try to put an image in the asset folder instead of ../image?

Comment: Yes the path is correct, even if fuel shows me warning the operation will be completed and file is created, but it's not perfect solution.

Comment: It seems that the error is related to the "image load" method and not with upload. "Image load" can load an image only if it is in the public asset folder, are sure that your upload functionality puts the new image there?

Answer (score 1):

This would help (You have to save Image files on public asset or wherever you want before resizing the file)

```
public function post_add_image()
{
    \Upload::process(array(
    'path'        => '../images/',
    'normalize'   => true,
    'change_case' => 'lower',
    'randomize'   => true,
    'ext_whitelist' => array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'),
    'max_size'    => 1024 * 1024,

    ));

   if (!\Upload::is_valid()) {
       return $this->response(\Upload::get_errors());
   } else {

       // Here comes the fix

       Upload::save();
       $saved_image = Upload::get_files();
       $original_name = $saved_image[0]['name'];
       $file_name = $saved_image[0]['saved_as'];  

       $public_asset_path_img = "assets".DS."img";

       $image = Image::load(DOCROOT.$public_asset_path_img.DS.$file_name, false, $file['extension']);
       $image->resize('800');
       $image->save(DOCROOT.$public_asset_path_img.DS.$file_name);


   }

   return $this->response(\Upload::get_files());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be with calling `Upload::save()` after you're trying to resize the image.  The uploaded file will be put into the PHP tmp folder, hence your `/tmp/phpOnZReS`.

Try moving your `Upload::save()` to just before your `foreach (\Upload::get_files() as $file)` loop and see if that helps.